# shopping cart magento 1.9 empty

Tags: magento

The shopping cart button on the category page does not work, products not added to the cart, cart empty after redirect. The cart button on the detail page works fine. Can somebody help please ?

This is the cart button code from firebug.

```
<button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.feelgoodstores.nl/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5mZWVsZ29vZHN0b3Jlcy5ubC9lbGVjdHJvbmljcy5odG1s/product/392/')" title="In winkelwagen" type="button">
```

Comment: How are you creating the code from that button?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you don't have a form-key added to the url. If you check the default urls you'll see that they end with: /form_key/random_text. For example:

http://www.mywebsite.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5rdW5zdGdyYXMtZ3Jhc3RhcGlqdC5ubC9rdW5zdGdyYXMtZ3Jhc3RhcGlqdC9ob21lcGFudW5hL21lZXN0LXZlcmtvY2h0L29jZWFuLmh0bWw,/product/6699/form_key/XCKYHCIhSilgSJnD/

This is a complete and working url to add an item to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem happened to me with magento version 1.9.0.1. I increased memory limit 128M to 256M in htaccess. Problem gone. Suddenly same error came again. Increased memory limit again to 512M. Solved. Don't know if same thing will happen again.

Comment: Wow, it appears you had another kind of error. You only apply a bad fix...the problem in your case seems to be a different thing.